# Do GET requests in AJAX load all images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, optimization

I'm rather new to `AJAX` and typically I just manhandle things to make them work.
If using a, `type:GET` `AJAX` request for a url that contains a lot of images on it.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/works/" + x,
    success: postImgModal
  });
```

On success: returns a bunch of HTML of divs and large images come into memory *(sorry i dont know know the correct words)* ?

When that requests return, will all those images be rendered?  Therefore,not very optimized? or do they come in as plain text which is very small?

I know developer tools has some waterfall views on working with front/backend optimizations; unfortunately, those views don't make sense to me. Could you guys suggest any tutorials that may help me understanding front/back end optimizations and how to use chrome tools (or other suggested tools) to my benefit. Hopefully, in the future,I can solve these questions myself. Or at least pose better questions.

Comment: what happens when you insert the html response of `ajax` call into your page? Do your images load?

Comment: Yes it woudl load all the images if I inserted the html into the page.  But so would the JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an AJAX request returns HTML, that's all that happens — the HTML text is returned. If you never add that HTML to your DOM, then that's the end of it.

If you *do* add the HTML to the DOM, then that's when any `<img>` tags will be examined. If the image data at the given URLs is not available in the browser cache, then separate HTTP requests will be made.

If you want to avoid that, you can use [data URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/data_URIs) in your HTML, though as one should expect (with a grimace) that's complicated by the prevalence of Internet Explorer.

Comment: I don't really have any use for this but I'm curious.  Can you serve up multiple images in one HTTP request? Say when you did that ajax request which had 10 images of text would those images be individually requested from wherever or would could they be groupped?

Comment: @MatthewHarwood yes, that's one way to do it. You could also serve up raw image data (RGB pixels, or some compressed form) and render those to a `<canvas>`.

Comment: I know there are prob better time investments for optimization.  However, do you know an resources to learn about the RGB pixels + canvas stuff?  Is it worth it at all? lol my e-peen grows on these things.

Comment: aneasier way to combine images is by using "CSS Sprites"

Comment: That's not always an option but a great consideration, if possible.  Making a checklist of things to consider on trello!

Comment: @MatthewHarwood the Canvas API for raw pixels is dirt simple - just "getImageData" and "putImageData", [described here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D).